# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when android intent

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking

I am trying to open an app using a custom url scheme.

I ran into the following error while testing through adb before deployment.

```
Exception occurred while executing 'start':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option: -
    at android.content.Intent.parseCommandArgs(Intent.java:8358)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.makeIntent(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:349)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.runStartActivity(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:451)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerShellCommand.onCommand(ActivityManagerShellCommand.java:192)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onShellCommand(ActivityManagerService.java:13144)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:965)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:839)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:6044)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3642)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

I tried to open it with the following command.

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW - "onionmarkethost://onionmarket.open" kr.gowoonwoori.oniontime`

This code is the manifest code for me to create a custom schema.

```
<activity android:name=".schema.SchemaActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="onionmarkethost"
                    android:scheme="onionmarket.open" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

What's the matter? I really don't know. Please, Help me.

Comment: "What's the matter?" -- you seem to have a plain `-` after `android.intent.action.VIEW`. Why is that there? Should it be a full option, with a letter after the `-`?

Comment: follow this answer : **https://stackoverflow.com/a/69765051/11138845**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the hyphen '-' after 'android.intent.action.VIEW' and use a single space instead before your url scheme

Answer (score 0):

You have missed -d before adding URI.

The general syntax for testing an intent filter URI with adb is:

```
 $ adb shell am start
            -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
            -d <URI> <PACKAGE>
```

For example, the command below tries to view a target app activity that is associated with the specified URI.

```
  $ adb shell am start
            -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW
            -d "example://gizmos" com.example.android
```

Refer this doc.
[Test your deep links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking#testing-filters)